# show only empty available times

Tags: 7, views, services, datetime

I am using the Calendar and Services Views modules.

What I am trying to achieve is a service view (JSON) that only lists available times for that day (hours list). It would be nice if, when a new event is created from 9:00am to 9:30am, that event is NOT included in the JSON, but only its available time.

Has anyone accomplished something similar before? I'm having difficulty getting started.